# Calculate variable based on remainder

Tags: javascript, math, equation, equation-solving

How do I use JavaScript to calculate the `x` value in this formula?

```
(x * y) % z = 1
```

`y` and `z` are known integers.

For example, `y = 7`, `z = 20`. 3 multiplied by 7 results into 21, that divided by 20 results into remainder of 1. Solution `x = 3`.

(3 * 7) % 20 = 1

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is this homework for a class?

Comment: @j08691 Why is that always the first question? `x = eval("((x * " + y + ") % " + z + " = 1)");` doesn't work at least. That's what I've tried. Results into `Invalid left-hand side in assignment `

Comment: @pseudosavant No it's not.

Comment: Are you sure x isn't equal to 23? This equation doesn't guarantee a single answer. Regarding your attempt, Javascript cannot do symbolic algebra, you will need to write a function of y and z that returns x.

Comment: It's always the first question because we like to see that you've put some effort into trying to resolve your problem, and haven't come here  as a first resort for someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a math question, not a JavaScript question. Use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). For example, to find the inverse of 7 modulo 20, start with these two equations:

```
20 =  0•7 + 1•20.
 7 =  1•7 + 0•20.
```

Next, divide the two numbers on the left (20/7) and take the integer part (2). The subtract that times the bottom equation from the one above it:

```
20 =  0•7 + 1•20.
 7 =  1•7 + 0•20.
 6 = -2•7 + 1•20.
```

Repeat: The integer part of 7/6 is 1. Subtract one times the bottom equation from the one above it. The new equation is:

```
 1 =  3•7 - 1•20.
```

Now you can see that 3 times 7 is 1 modulo 20. (Simultaneously, -1 times 20 is 1 modulo 7.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's more than one number that is valid for `x`. `x` could also be 23 in this case (23 * 7 = 161, and 161 % 20 = 1). So you need to express the problem a bit differently as a starting point, such as "what is the lowest x that can solve the equation?"

If you're solving that then it is suddenly a different problem. You then only need to solve for two possibilities: `(x * y) - z = 1`, and `(x * y) = 1`. From there you can do a little algebra to solve for `x`.